# Angular2 Async call value undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below html and ts code - when I debug the typescript code I am not getting any values in params it is because when the value is passed the backend call is not made so it sends undefined. how can I delay the html call that way I can get the values?

html file:

```
   <button (click)="test()">
       <component [param]="param"></component>
   </button>
```

ts file:

```
   @Input param: any;    
      test() {
        this.service.getData()
          .subscribe((val) => {
            this.param = val;
          });
    }
```

Comment: To delay, what do you mean? can you explain it more?

Comment: I mean to pass the data to the component after the backend call is complete

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put an `*ngIf` on the component and only show it when `param` becomes truthy.

```
<button (click)="test()">
       <component *ngIf="!!param" [param]="param"></component>
</button>
```

Another way is to pass a default value until `param` becomes truthy;

```
<button (click)="test()">
       <component [param]="param ? param : 'hello world'"></component>
</button>
```

We are passing `hello world` as default but you can pass whatever you like.

Comment: Is there a way to delay the call to the component since what if I get 'hello world' from the backend?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: like delay passing the value to the component that way I get the data from the backend I am worried to pass default value since in case I pass undefined and if we may not get data from backend